# Why MEPs on the plenary session vote by show of hand and not electronically?

Tags: european-union

Despite having electronic voting available, MEPs vote by show of hands on the plenary session. Is there a specific reason behind this?

Likewise, even when electronic voting is used, usually individual votes are not recorded. Why would they discard this information?

Answer (score 3):

The reason seems to be a desire to streamline the voting process/get things done faster if [the EP's website](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?language=en&type=IM-PRESS&reference=20060628STO09319) is anything to go by:

> If we believe the statistics, since the start of their electoral term
>   in July 2004, MEPs have voted more than 25,000 times. European
>   Parliament voting is mainly via a show of hands, like the Greek
>   assembly under Pericles. The session president casts an eye over the
>   raised hands and judges where the majority lies, without counting the
>   exact number for or against. When a simple majority is required (a
>   majority of the members present) it is generally quick and simple.
>
> But sometimes the vote is tight and the decision of the president
>   might be contested by MEPs who raise their hands and call out "check,
>   check!" Also, if the President decides that the result is doubtful, the
>   President may decide to hold the vote again using the electronic
>   system and, if the latter is not working, by sitting and standing.
>   MEPs no longer raise their hands, instead they press a button (for,
>   against or abstaining) in the special box on their desks. Each MEP
>   must identify themselves by sliding an electronic card into the box.

Either way, it doesn't seem to prevent at least one website to track MEP voting records:

https://www.votewatch.eu/en/term8-voting-statistics.html